# iAd interstitial delegate methods doesn't get called

Tags: objective-c, iad, interstitial, adbannerview

I want to use interstitial ads in my app, so I implemented all necessary delegate methods.
The problem is, if I use [self requestInterstitialAdPresentation] to show the ad, only the interstitialAdDidLoad: method gets called.
The interstitialAdActionDidFinish: methods doesn't get called...

But if I use the deprecated [self.interstitial presentFromViewController:self] to show the ad, everything works.

**Is there anything new to implement to get things work ?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I resolved the problem.

Since IOS7 with its [iAd Additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) there's no need for an adInterstitialDelegate. The only thing to do, is preparing the ads or set the interstitialPresentationPolicy to something other than none (as you can read in the documentation) and as a last step requesting the ad using the requestInterstitialAdPresentation: method.

Comment: And, how do you know when the user taps the ad
- (BOOL) interstitialAdActionShouldBegin:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave

or when the add is closed
- (void)interstitialAdActionDidFinish:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd

If you can not use the delegate methods

Comment: When the ad is closed, viewDidAppear in your view controller will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 9.2.1, Xcode 7.2.1, ARC enabled

@Jellyjoey I confirmed, `viewDidAppear` is called when the ad is closed.  And as you might expect, when you tap the ad, `viewDidDisappear` gets called.

It has to do with how you are presenting the interstitial ad:

> Completing an Advertising Action
>
> If the full-screen ad displayed the rich media ad inside your app, it
>   calls your delegate’s interstitialAdActionDidFinish: method after the
>   ad finishes. Your implementation of this method should restore any
>   services paused by your app when the action started.
>
> Important: If your app was moved into the background because the
>   willLeave parameter was YES, then the app’s user interface is never
>   covered by the banner view and your app does not receive a call to
>   interstitialAdActionDidFinish:. However, if your interface was covered
>   by the banner view, your app could still be moved into the background
>   later, either because the advertisement launched another app or
>   because the user chose to do so. In all cases, if your user interface
>   was covered by the banner view, it is uncovered and your delegate’s
>   interstitialAdActionDidFinish: is invoked before your app moves to the
>   background. Because the app may be moving into the background, your
>   delegate should return quickly from its interstitialAdActionDidFinish:
>   method.

To view the excerpt above and the rest of the guidelines for interstitial ads:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Full-ScreenAdvertisements/Full-ScreenAdvertisements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH5-SW24

Here are two examples provided by Apple of how to use full page ads:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdInterstitialSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010627-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2